# Draw a visualizing diagram OpenCV SVM data set

Tags: opencv, svm

I am new to OpenCV SVM. Is there a way to plot a graph or develop some visual content for the trained data set that is developed by OpenCV svm so that I can check if my training data is accurate and tune my SVM parameters accordingly ?

Comment: OpenCV doesn't have built-in functions to draw... You'd better save your data non csv and plot them in Matlab or similar

Comment: I have the yml and xml file that opencv produces.. But I couldn't figure out how to parse it using matlab/octave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to visualize the SVM responses and can be done using OpenCV drawing capabilities.

*This question is already old, but it shows up high in Google results for visualizing SVM. I answer for anyone who may find this question.*

There is an SVM tutorial with example code here:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html

**It contains a code for visualizing what the SVM has learned**. Note that this example shows data on a plane so it will work only if your data is 2D.

So this code below (it comes from the linked OpenCV docs) creates a image 512 x 512 px and for each pixel checks if it was classified as belonging to one class or another (response 1 or -1). On top of it, the data points are marked so you are able to see if the SVM classification works well.

```
// Train the SVM
CvSVM SVM;
SVM.train(trainingDataMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);

Vec3b green(0,255,0), blue (255,0,0);
// Show the decision regions given by the SVM
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
    {
        Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1,2) << j,i);
        float response = SVM.predict(sampleMat);

        if (response == 1)
            image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)  = green;
        else if (response == -1)
             image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)  = blue;
    }

// Show the training data
int thickness = -1;
int lineType = 8;
circle( image, Point(501,  10), 5, Scalar(  0,   0,   0), thickness, lineType);
circle( image, Point(255,  10), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);
circle( image, Point(501, 255), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);
circle( image, Point( 10, 501), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);
```

This is a good approach if your data points are pairs of integers. If you have `float` data points you need to decide what resolution of visualization you want and make pixel represent not a 1 x 1 block but your demanded minimal resolution (e.g. 5.0e-27 x 2.0e-24)

Comment: Thanks mate.. I am doing something very different now so cant try it right now. but will surely check if it works. I'll accept the answer even if it helps someone else.

Comment: Hi @molecule, did you try this out? If it answers your question, you can accept the answer.

Comment: hi, I am accepting the answer for now until someone says it doesn't work.